# Algorithm that matches decimal number to expression in terms of mathematical constants

Tags: algorithms, math-software

I remember finding at some point a type of algorithm which provided a decimal value with enough precision, would try to match it to expressions in terms of mathematical constants (for example, plugging in $5.85987448204$ would return $\pi+e$.)

But I cant't seem to find anything like this on the internet, so does anybody have any idea about how these algorithms are called, or where I could find something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Simon Plouffe's *Inverse Symbolic Calculator*](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) and [Robert Munafo's *RIES - Find Algebraic Equations, Given Their Solution*](https://mrob.com/pub/ries/).

Answer (score 1):

You might explore [Ries](https://mrob.com/pub/ries/), specifically [about the Ries algorithm](https://mrob.com/pub/ries/index-2.html#algorithm).